# Locking position when resizing NSView frame

Tags: cocoa, alignment, position, frame, nsview

When I re-size my custom NSView's frame its position ends up changing. Basically I want it to lock it's position at the top left so when I change the width or height it expands right or down. Kinda hard to explain but think about like text alignment.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a flipped coordinate system, see the second example in the [Transforming the Coordinate System](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Coordinates/Coordinates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH10-SW10) section.

> A flipped coordinate system is useful when the contents of a view naturally originate at the top of a view, and flow downwards. For example, a view that scrolls text up and off the screen as new text appears would be best implemented using a flipped coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, you want to setSubViesResizingMask, property for each subviews....